# Making a forum without manual page refresh (without AJAX or Javascript)

Tags: php, forum

for a schoolproject I am making a forum that has to work synchronized because its goal is having a discussion in real time for an arranged period. So it's important to see on each single moment new updates.

For now my forum looks good but it has one big problem. When I am logged in, I can see immediately my posts. But when someone else posted something in between, I can only see it when I post a new reaction or doing a manual page refresh. Of course this is very irritating.

I know that it is possible to fix that with AJAX and/or Javascript but the problem is that my forum has to work without this two things. So I was looking for solutions but I didn't find what I looked for.

Every answer I found they use Javasript or Ajax. When I was writing my question here, I founded another simular one that looks the same ("Refresh a Div, Table or TR without reloading page and without using Ajax"), but when I looked in the answer, I saw Javasript. So it still isn't what I looking for.

I have also tried to put the code, for seeing the updates, on an other place in my code. but even then it doesn't work. I hope that someone can help me to make it good.

Kirsten

Ps: sorry if there are some little faults in my English

### Here is a sample of my code

```
include('jeugdhulp_2-0_connectie.php');
include('klasses/Reacties.class.php');  

$reactie = new Reacties();
$stellingen = $reactie->ToonStelling();

//$recenteactiviteiten = $reactie->ToonRecenteReacties();

if(!empty($_POST['tekst_gebruiker']))
{
    $reactie->Reactie = $_POST['tekst_gebruiker'];
    $reactie->ID = $_SESSION["gebruikersid"];       
    try
    {
        $reactie->Save();
        //$reactie->ToonStelling();
        //$feedback = "Uw gegevens werden bewaard!";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
else
{
    $feedback = "";
}
//altijd recente reacties laten zien
$recenteactiviteiten = $reactie->ToonRecenteReacties();
```

Comment: You'll need JS or some other client side tech for this behavior. Flash  is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow similar to the way Facebook is doing, which is pushing the data to users instead of waiting for the users to reload the page. I have some very interesting sources for you to discover, maybe you will find something meaningful there :)

Have you ever heard of [Comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) before? It helps you to push the data towards users " without the browser explicitly requesting it".

[Ape project](http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.htmlAjax) is also a useful place for you to look at. It facilitates Ajax Push for realtime web, which is what you are looking for.

Happy discovering and keep in mind that without Javascript and AJAX, nothing you can do to make your forum being **realtime**.

Comment: Hey BeingSimpler, it's indeed similar to the way Facebook is doing. I will certainly discover your sources. I was not sure, that's why my question on this site, but now I know that maybe it would be better to set up another project for this task.

Comment: Yes I'm sure you're gonna solve it soon, if you seriously look at those links above ;) Just to let you know what without Javascript and AJAX, you can't make your site realtime. Hope my links will definitely recommend you something for your work (and if it helps, please tick right for me).

Comment: You will still need Javascript in some form. With Javascript you can do all sorts of things, but without you are limited to changes when the user reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Absent using Ajax and Javascript HTML is static and will only show new data when the page is reloaded. So in short you can't

Comment: Ok. thx for your reaction. I also thought it before, but maybe I was wrong so I posted this question here. It was my php teacher who said to me: "it has to work synchronized without AJAX and Javascript". Now I will look for other solutions then :).

Answer (score 0):

If you hate the javascript use `<iframe>` and  [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: This is gonna be a real waste of the resource :) Think if 100 people visiting and reloading the page every 10 seconds.

Comment: 10 request per seconds is not heavy, and there is no difference for server load between request from meta refresh and ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) (within a frame eventually) but it won't be real time; meta-refresh uses a timer to automatically call for the page

edit: with ajax it won't be real time either unless you "listen" for updates pushed by the server through the connection you make back to the server; otherwise you'd be using a timer, still

Comment: This is gonna be a real waste of the resource :) Think if 100 people visiting and reloading the page every 10 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you guys were saying about loading the whole page using meta refresh, if you're using an iframe then it is of course perfectly fine, my bad though, but it somehow isn't much related to the question here. And, your words are insulting, so I'll mark it. You just need to tell me what's wrong and I would be happy to look over it again. Voted up again.